# Call a function after previous function is complete reactjs

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to call function `this.onLoggin()` after `this.props.verifyCode(params);` already done, how can i do it.
here is myfunction:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let params = {
            email: this.props.email,
            codeVerify: this.state.code
        }
        this.props.verifyCode(params);
        this.onLoggin();

    }

onLoggin = () =>{
        if(this.props.isVerify === true){
            const body = {
                username: this.props.user.username,
                password: this.props.user.password
            }
            this.props.loggin(body);
        }
    }
```

`verifyCode` come from redux:

```
const AUTHEN_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/client/user-info-client/regist';

const verifyCode = (params) => dispatch => {
    axios.post(AUTHEN_URL, null, {params})
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
            type: VERIFY_CODE,
            payload: res.data.data,
        })});
}

export default verifyCode;
```

here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
        isVerify: false
};

const verifyCode = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case VERIFY_CODE:
            return {
                isVerify: true
            }
        default:
            return state;

    }
}

export default verifyCode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed that `this.props.verifyCode(params)` is an asynchronous function. You have to either use `async await` method or `.then`.

Using `.then`:

```
this.props.verifyCode(params).then(response => this.onLoggin()).catch(error => error)
```

Using `async await`:

```
onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let params = {
            email: this.props.email,
            codeVerify: this.state.code
        }
        try{
            await this.props.verifyCode(params);
            this.onLoggin();
        }
        catch(error){
             return error
        }


    }
```

The axios request

```
const verifyCode = (params) => dispatch => {
    return axios.post(AUTHEN_URL, null, {params})
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
            type: VERIFY_CODE,
            payload: res.data.data,
        })
        return res.data
      });
}
```

If this doesn't work. Can you try the async await method?

Hope this helps

Comment: thank for your help, but when i use .then() i get an error: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of undefined". when i use async await, it doesn't work. this.props.isVerify in this.onLoggin() will be true when this.props.verifyCode(params) done but it is false untill render() is called

Comment: It's probably because the axios request is not returning anything. I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks alot, why i have to set return of axios request to use .then and async await?

Comment: It's because axios will return a promise. You can read all about promises here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 1):

Your verifyCode is a redux action. You need to add a reducer to make use of the information received as a response. Also, add the reducer while configuring store.

```
export const verification = (state = { isVerify : false, loginInfo : null}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.VERIFY_CODE:
      return {...state, isVerify : true, loginInfo: action.payload};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Then, proceed to matchStateToProps and use

```
if(this.props.verification.isVerify === true)
```

to check if the user has successfully verified. You can also add further conditional rendering using `this.props.verification.loginInfo`

Answer (score 0):

verifyCode() function return a promise so you can catch the promise and then after finishing function you can call this.onLoggin().

```
 onSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let params = {
                email: this.props.email,
                codeVerify: this.state.code
            }
            const data = this.props.verifyCode(params);
            data.then(result => {
               this.onLoggin();
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });          
        }
```

Comment: thank for your help but always get error: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" when using .then()